# WPF Tips for graphically displaying a sequence on/off durations

Tags: wpf, graphics

I'm working on an application where users can select between multiple sequences of on/off durations. Sequences always start with the on period and can have a varying length (but always in on/off pairs): e.g.

```
var sequences = new []
{
    new int[] { 10, 15 },        // 10 ms on, 15 ms off
    new int[] { 15, 10, 5, 10 }  // 15 ms on, 10 ms off, 5 ms on, 10 ms off
};
```

The sequences have a maximum duration of 10 seconds and will be repeated. One special sequence defines no on/off durations: it is always on (though I might be able to change that to {1,0} or something).

Instead of displaying the numbers on screen I'd like to show a little graphical representation for the full 10 second duration (repeating shorter sequences) so the user can compare patterns. These will be displayed in a combo box that resizes with the window. For the examples above it would look something like the following (where X is a filled in background)

```
xx   xx   xx   xx   xx   xx   xx...
xxx  x  xxx  x  xxx  x  xxx  x  ...
```

I suppose I'll have to use a value converter (if only for the special value), but am uncertain what the best/easiest way of creating the graphs is, especially with the resize requirement and repeating the shorter sequences. A canvas, something else?

I'd greatly appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow this basic approach:

1. Write a value converter that takes each sequence and repeats the sequence into the full 10 seconds, encoding each chunk of time with a class that specifies whether the period is 'On' and the duration.
2. For each sequence, bind to the ItemsSource of an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx).  For the ItemsPanel, use a StackPanel with Horizontal orientation.  For the ItemTemplate, use a Rectangle or whatever other visual you'd like for a chunk of time, with the Width bound to the duration.  You've also included a handy 'IsOn' property now so that you can easily visualize the On/Off state.  Don't worry about scaling the Width at this point.
3. Place the ItemsControl in a [ViewBox](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html), which can be allowed to stretch to its parent container.  Now you have a visual that provides the correct proportions of duration and scales with size.

---

Here's a bare-bones implementation (no error handling or any attempt to make it pretty):

UDPATE: Fixed a bug that didn't properly truncate repeating sequence at 10 seconds.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace TestWpf
{
    public class SeqSegment
    {
        public bool IsOn { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
    }

    public class SeqConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var result = new List<SeqSegment>();
            var seq = (int[]) value;
            int time = 0;
            int i = 0;
            bool isOn = true;
            while (time < 10000)
            {
                result.Add(new SeqSegment { Duration = Math.Min(seq[i], 10000 - time), IsOn = isOn });
                isOn = !isOn;
                time += seq[i];
                i++;
                if (i >= seq.Length)
                    i = 0;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public IEnumerable<int[]> TestSequences
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new[] {10, 5000, 10, 8};
                yield return new[] {500, 5000};
                yield return new[] {50, 400, 30, 10};
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:TestWpf="clr-namespace:TestWpf" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <TestWpf:SeqConverter x:Key="SeqConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SeqSegTemplate">
            <Rectangle x:Name="Rect" Width="{Binding Duration}" Fill="Blue"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOn}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Rect" Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SeqTemplate">
            <Viewbox Height="50" Stretch="Fill">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SeqConverter}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SeqSegTemplate}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="1"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TestSequences}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SeqTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I use a combo box instead of an items control, and the display of the sequence is fine, except for one thing: instead of scaling the content, the viewbox grows. I've got a grid in the combobox template with three columns with Widths: Auto, Auto and *. The sequence (viewbox) is displayed in the 3rd column, but won't limit its size.

Comment: @Stefan, that's correct, if you place it in a * column, the ViewBox will attempt to grow.  I don't see any way around providing a fixed Width, as the ComboBox drop-down will try to grow to accommodate its listed items and therefore does not provide any width layout suggestions to the contents.  If you do want it to change Width, what should the Width be relative to?

Comment: The combobox changes it's width with the window, it's in a * column of the main grid in the window. I want the first two columns in the combobox to auto size, and the graph to full up the rest of the combobox. Is there no way to change the behaviour of the container in the combobox to provide the layout suggestions?

Comment: I eventually managed to do it with a databinding on the viewbox width to a hidden control that resize the way I want.